# Unity WebGL build missing sharedassets1.resource on loading and not playing videos

Tags: unity-game-engine, webassembly, unity-webgl

In my project I have couple of "screens" which have videos playing on them. Usual .mp4 files attached to 3D object.

When I Play it in the editor - all works as expected. No errors. Not problems.

When I build the project for WebGL and play it online - everything works except these videos. Looking at the console I see this error:

```
sharedassets1.resource:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (File not found)
```

It repeats 6 times = I have 6 videos.

What is this file `sharedassets1.resource`? I don't see it anywhere? In the error the link to the file expects it here: `http://localhost:8000/main/sharedassets1.resource` - in the `main` folder. But that's my folder structure of the Successful build:

[image]

What should I check? What kind of settings might be not right?

Any ideas/knowledge appreciated! Thanks!

**UPDATE WITH SOLUTION DETAILS:**

Below suggestion can solve this. However this means that you need to check the format of your videos (mp4? mov? avi?) and convert them to something that WebGL can stream without any issues. For example `.webm` will work PERFECTLY but only if the game is played via chrome.

Comment: What folder is your video located in?

Comment: @0xBFE1A8 In the Editor it's Assets > Videos > video01.mp4 ...video02.mp4...etc.

Comment: Please provide your code.

Comment: @0xBFE1A8 there is no custom code around these videos. In the editor - i dropped them on the CUBEs and in the Inspector that added Component Video Player. That component, on each cube has a reference to the video file in Assets > Videos. They play on load of the scene. In the Editor Play mode - all is fine. But build online - throws out that error as above:(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In editor create a folder with the name **StreamingAssets** and put your video files into it.

Comment: Ah! I get you point - then the build just takes this folder as is and i need to set the Vieo Player component to URL and point to the video files. 

Tried that - than a different WebGL issue pops up - "google says" it's then some specific WebGL problem many struggle with. Related to WebGL video streaming problems:(

Comment: Ok! this worked if I convert the video to different formats:) Thanks for the tip! It's a little annoying that it can't be a bit more "format independent" but this can work!:)